# How do you return a list after a for loop?

Tags: python

Currently they are in separate list, the output should be in an array list [3, 2, 2, 2]

```
lst1 = ["31245", "12354", "15342", "12543"]
str1 = "12345"

for ele in lst1:

    resLst = []
    count = 0
    i = 0

    while i < len(str1) :
        if ele[i] != str1[i] :
            count += 1  
        i += 1 
    resLst.append(count)
    print(resLst)

Output:
[3]
[2]
[2]
[2]
```

Comment: if all the values are unique, you may find a `set()` cleaner here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the following which makes use of a `for` and `enumerate` to grab the index of the current letter. Note that strings in Python can be iterated as arrays which make them easy to navigate:

```
lst1 = ["31245", "12354", "15342", "12543"]
str1 = "12345"
resLst = []

for ele in lst1:
    count = 0
    for i, letter in enumerate(ele):
        if letter != str1[i]:
            count += 1
    resLst.append(count)

print(resLst)

# [3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your code:

- You're clearing the values of `resList` in every iteration.
- You're printing the list inside the loop.

So you would have to do:

```
resLst = []
for ele in lst1:

    count = 0
    i = 0

    while i < len(str1) :
        if ele[i] != str1[i] :
            count += 1  
        i += 1 
    resLst.append(count)
print(resLst)
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to make a list from a different list, a list comprehension is often a good choice. In this case you can use `sum()` since booleans are treated as `1` and `0`. This makes the problem very succinct. For each `s` in `lst1`, you zip the character of `str1` and count how many of the expression `a != b` are true :

```
lst1 = ["31245", "12354", "15342", "12543"]
str1 = "12345"

[sum(a != b for a, b in zip(str1, s)) for s in lst1]

# [3, 2, 2, 2]
```